# Gnuplot asymptotic line

Tags: graph, gnuplot

How can I fit a vertical asymptotic line to show (in the graph bellow) which is the maximum point in the x-axis?

[graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/axtcJ.png)

Here is the plotting code:

```
set parametric

set trange [0:pi]

a(t) = (1 + cos(t))/2

t1(t) = (t + sin(t))/2
R(t) = a(t)

rho(t) = 1/R(t)**3

rho2(t) = log(rho(t)/rho(0))

set xlabel "t"

set ylabel "log(rho)"

plot t1(t), rho2(t)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that there is no need for fitting in this particular case - one can directly substitute `pi` to `t1` in order to get the asymptotic `x`-value, i.e., `t1(pi) = pi/2` which is approximately equal to `1.5708`